# How to make mock consume some time rspec

Tags: rspec

I would like the rspec to consume certain amount of time and then return. For example, below is an logical line representing that I want rspec to mock a call to `some_method` and return true after 1 second. Is it possible?

```
expect(MyClass).to receive(:some_method).consume_time(1).and_return(true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`timecop`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to manipulate time. Use a [block](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation) to mock the body of the method.

```
expect(MyClass).to receive(:some_method) do
  Timecop.travel(Time.now + 1)
  true
end
```

Note that if you're mocking `some_method` to test something else that probably should be an `allow`.

Using `Timecop` without a block has global effect. Be sure to call `Timecop.return` to reset the flow of time, perhaps in an [`after` hook](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) to ensure it happens. You can even add this to RSpec globally so you never forget.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after { Timecop.return }
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Schwern for the response. I get ```unexpected return (LocalJumpError)```. My return statement of method returns multiple values though. like ```return 1, true``` so I do the same in block implementation but I get that error.

Comment: aah found it. You can fix LocalJumpError by removing return keyword from "return true". this is cause block statements don't have return. last line becomes return value.

Comment: Timecop actually does mock time travel. Doesn't really consume any time. "sleep" worked  for me. I would still accept cause it can be used for different usecase. I might have been unable to clarify that I actually wanted a mock to take a time

Comment: yes I actually want to make sure it receives a call to "some_method" hence use of expect vs. allow.

Comment: @explorer If you actually need your method to consume 1 real second in testing, yes, use `sleep`. But do you? `sleep` is typically avoided in testing because it slows everything down, better to just change the clock. What's your use case?

Comment: So i spin up a thread in my code for which i await for couple seconds in main execution. I was looking into writing unit tests to verify the behavior if spawned thread makes main execution wait for 1 second. Sleeping 1 second don't seem like a big deal and Timecop since it runs the clock ahead I do see that Time.now in main execution don't get the forwarded clock because both are in separate OS context.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [block](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation) to mock the body of the method.

```
expect(MyClass).to receive(:some_method) do
  sleep(1)
  true
end
```